# How can I remove NoSuchElementException error delay ( occurs using find_element(By.~ , "").text )

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium for review crawling.

There is some reviews have no text.

when I crawl those using find_element(By.~ , "").text, The function return NoSuchElementException error.

I can catch the error, but time delay is too long for crawling

Is there any solution to remove this delay

help me plz ^^/

The crawling code is here

```
    try:
        review = item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSS_REVIEW).text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        review = ""
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        review = ""
        print(f"Exception error : {e}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the delay before `NoSuchElementException` and no explicit waits defined, the reason could be that the `implicitly_wait` allpied which is not 0..

So, try to set it to 0.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(0) 

//do some text search
//then return implicitly_wait back
driver.implicitly_wait(<some_default_value>) # seconds
```